# Find Combined Probability of one Die and two Coins Tossed

Tags: probability

> A fair die and two unbiased coins are tossed. What are possible outcomes of each object and the probability of each outcome?

**My solution:**

- Probability for a fair Die $D$: $\frac{1}{6}$
- Probability for unbiased Coin $C_1$:  $\frac{1}{2}$
- Probability for unbiased Coin $C_2$: $\frac{1}{2}$

So we can calculate it this way:

$$\Pr(D) * \Pr(C_1) * \Pr(C_2) = \frac{1}{6} * \frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{6 * 2 * 2} = \frac{1}{24}$$

*or*

$$\frac{1}{\binom{6}{1} \binom{2}{1} \binom{2}{1}} = \frac{1}{6 * 2 * 2} = \frac{1}{24}$$

**Is this correct?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have outcomes with probability $P[(D,C_1,C_2)=(d,c_1,c_2)]=1/24$ with  for $1\leq d\leq 6$, and $(c_1,c_2)\in \{H,T\}^2.$